# Git: Version control of production code?

Tags: git

I'm a web developer, we have a production site that is the latest & greatest of our site (lots of Coldfusion). Would it be wise to put our production site under version control as a git server?

Drawbacks? Benefits?

More or less, I'm envisioning that I will put git on the production side of things as the orgin branch/master then once we are ready to go live push to our production. Is that wise?

Comment: Define 'under version control'? Do you not already use version control for development? Is there anything on your public site that doesn't come directly from the development version control?

Comment: Are you talking about putting the code on a public git hosting service (ala github ?)

Comment: We do not currently have git deployed, we're working on using that for development. Can I setup my production site as a git repo so all I have to do is do a push/merge to deploy the new code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't push to a non-bare repository, because your push might overwrite changes in the working directory that your local repo can't know about.

Most people using git for deployment like you're talking about have their production directory as a git repository, and they pull TO it, from INSIDE it to get updates. Either from a central repo somewhere, or an integration manager's local repo, or something like that.

Comment: Well, you'd work locally (I work with a local server environment--MAMP, in my case), then commit and push to a central repo. Then you'd go to the server's web root directory and `git pull` the changes you just pushed. You could even automate that with a post-receive hook on the central repository.

Answer (score 0):

Use .gitignore to ignore files that only bloat the repository. Your repository size will only go up, better use the space properly.
Branching will help you test things out and only then integrate them with the main branch.
Git is really fast because it doesn't need to access the server for most operations.

Answer (score 0):

Any version control is useful in development phase. When you are talking about your web application then it becomes a deployment environment.

In an ideal world you could move all you website parts like images, video, static content, dynamic content etc in GiT.

You could then develop a script to push those changes co